# Unable to change default values in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using following code

```
window.onload = function(){
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)";
    Chart.defaults.global = { 
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
    tooltipFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
    tooltipFontSize: 24,
    tooltipFontStyle: "bold",
    tooltipFontColor: "green",
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
```

I am unable to change many values at once. When I write the code above the chart disappears altogether.

Comment: If the answer below is the one you're looking for, please set it as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your default before creating the chart.

```
window.onload = function(){
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)";
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
};
```

If you want to change multiple options at once you must follow the same pattern that you do for one.  The following code redefines Chart.defaults.global.  (i.e. Chart.defaults.global will only have the tooltipFillColor property.  All other properties will be destroyed).

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
  tooltipFillColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)"
};
```

Instead, you want to redefine each individual property:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor ="rgba(255,0,0,0.8)";
Chart.defaults.globaltooltipFontFamily ="'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.globaltooltipFontSize =24;
Chart.defaults.globaltooltipFontStyle ="bold";
Chart.defaults.globaltooltipFontColor = "green";
```

Comment: Hey, thank you it is working. Actually I wanted to change many values at once. Could you please see the modified question?